# Extending DbContext to use generic Entry(...)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

This isn't a question as much as its a crowd-sourced code review...

I noticed you can use context.Entry(itemToModify) for adding objects as well as update & delete with one catch, itemToModify's type has to be specified, it can not be generic.

If I could get around the generic types issue, I could eliminate and simplify my code.

Here's what I did, it works locally, let me know what you think, if you see problems etc.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool ModifyContext<T>(this DbContext context, T itemToModify, EntityState state) where T : class
    {
        // Function that throws a null arg exception 
        ValidationFunctions.IsNotNull(itemToModify);

        context.Entry(itemToModify).State = state;

        return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
}

public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly SomeContext _context = new SomeContext();

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a person
    /// </summary>
    public bool Add(Person personToAdd)
    {
        return _context.ModifyContext(personToAdd, EntityState.Added);
    }

    // Edit, Delete etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your code. Why do you use this:

```
 var type = itemToModify.GetType();
 var item = Convert.ChangeType(itemToModify, (Type)type);
 context.Entry(item).State = state;
```

When you have strongly typed entity?

Why not use just this:

```
context.Entry(itemToModify).State = state;
```

or

```
context.Entry<T>(itemToModify).State = state;
```

Comment: I originally commented with out coding the changes first, it doesn't appear to be as simple as swapping to the generic version of Entry.  I'm going to look in to this further and I'll post when I have a better idea of the issue

Comment: In the original code you couldn't plug in itemToModify directly for TEntity. In the non-generic Entry() TEntity has a requirement that it be a class, and itemToModify could have been any type (reference or not). By adding the class restriction the line: 'context.Entry(itemToModify).State' now works. My original code went around the issue by getting the class type of itemToModify and converted the object back to that type. While it worked, it was confusing and was doing extra work.  Thanks for your help.